# AngularJS controller not registered Error

Tags: angularjs

I tried every solution on stackoverflow to make this error go but all to vain..
I am trying to use ngRoute to make SPA.

```
angular.js:14328 Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name 'loginCtrl' is not registered.
```

Here is my code

```js
/* route file called controoler.js */
var app = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute']).

config(['$routeProvider',

  function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'login/views/loginView.html',
        controller: 'loginCtrl'
      })
      .when('/reward', {
        templateUrl: 'rewardManagement/views/reward.html'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  }
]);


// loginCtrl in login/controllers/loginCtrl.js

var app = angular.module('mainApp', []);
app.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $http, $location) {

  $scope.changeView = function(view) {
    $location.path(view); // path not hash
  };


}]);
```

```html
<!-- -------index.html--------- -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="body-full-height" ng-app="mainApp">

<head>
  <script src="/controller.js"></script>
  <script src="../login/controllers/loginCtrl.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="loginCtrl"></div>
  <ng-view></ng-view>

</body>

</html>


<!-- -------loginView.html--------- -->
<script src="../login/controllers/loginCtrl.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="loginCtrl">
  <button ng-click="changeView('/reward')">Please Bypass this for now</button>
</div>
```

Please suggest a solution, in my project I will have many links which when clicked should change the ng-view according to the route. And I don't think putting all the .js scripts in index.html is a good idea, shouldn't each partial contain its own .js which also contains the controller?

Comment: remove `ng-controller="loginCtrl"`  from template and also remove `<div ng-controller="loginCtrl"></div>` from main html

Comment: This is all wrong, why do you redeclare your module (`var app = angular.module('mainApp', []);`), and why do you not injecting dependencies correctly (`app.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $http, $location)`), and why there's no `<ui-view>` container anywhere?

Comment: Oh, ignore my remark about `<ui-view>` (I thought you were using `ui-router`)

Comment: No, I am using ngRouter.. What is the correct way then?

Comment: @Hadi I removed that but now loginView is not displayed. I must be doing something totally wrong..Can u help?

Comment: @Tidya What you did is fine, read my suggestions about the module redeclaration and the dependencies injunction, and also don't load js files from the **view**, don't forget - This is a _SPA_ (Single Page Application)

Comment: @AlonEitan I made the changes, but now loginView is not generated.

Comment: @Tidya What did you do exactly? What did you change in your code? You can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43570869/edit) and describe the attempts you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KVy6opYjfp3n8dtwpPzs?p=preview)

Just did some little changes in your controller code:

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {
  $scope.changeView = function(view) {
    $location.path(view); // path not hash
  };
}]);
```

Also you don't need to add the `script` again in your `loginView.html`

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the correct way to go about the following:
index.html loads loginView.html, when login is successful, I want a generic header and a sidebar to be loaded with a content that would change as user clicks the options in menu in the sidebar. 
The problem is I can't put the header and sidebar in index template as I don't want it in loginView.  ??

Comment: Well you can create index.html and put loginView.html in `ui-view` and when login is successful then you can use some other html file like navigation.html and can make use of `nested views` to achieve what you require.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:xyad7ztyMMOuKsK1TcKc?p=preview this may help you but this is based on `$stateProvider`

Comment: hmm I am currently using ngRoute.. How about I use ng-include for header and sidebar? I don't want to keep adding header and Sidebar in every .html file. Will that work? index->login->reward.html OR rewardList.html but both of these will include a common header.html using ng-include